# Iterating through Jira API Url

Tags: python, api, loops, while-loop, jira

I'm having issues iterating through the Jira API. My goal is to iterate until I extract the
`response['total']`which is 7,000 records. My `maxResults` is 1,000 per request.

I'm getting a successful response (status code= 200) and my correct 1,000 on `maxResults` but I'm not updating my `startAt`, which starts at 0, but I'm expecting to add up to the maxResults. My goal is to iterate through the Jira API to extract all the 7,000 records and append them together as dataframes.

[image]

```
baseUrl= https://example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=issuetype='Story'
total = 1
maxResults = 0
startAt = 0

while (startAt + maxResults) < total:
            data = []
            response = requests.get((baseUrl+'&startAt='+str(startAt + maxResults)), auth = (username, password))
            print(response.status_code)
            r = response.json()
            jiraIssues = r["issues"]

          
            for issue in issues:

                results_1= json.dumps((issues), sort_keys= True,indent = 4)

                results_2 =json.loads(results_1)

                results_3 = pd.json_normalize(results_2)

                data.append(results_3)

      
                print (len(issues))

                print (startAt)

                print("----------")

                maxResults = response['maxResults']

                total = response['total']

                startAt = response['startAt']

            else:

                break

                print("none")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate through the API results, you need to be incrementing your `startAt` parameter by adding `maxResults` to it at the end of every `while` loop iteration:

```
startAt = startAt + maxResults
```

The `startAt` parameter indicates the result number to begin at when retrieving results from your API call -- think of it like a "page" parameter. Each successive API call must request the next "page" of results in order to iterate through and reach the end of the results.