# Python Atlassian JIRA iterate for next page

Tags: python, jira

I followed the example described here:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Atlassian-Python-API-s/ba-p/2091355
to write a toy program to get through the list of JIRAs.

```py
from atlassian import Jira

jira = Jira(
    url='https://your-site.atlassian.net',
    username='email',
    password='token',
    cloud=True)

jql_request ='project = WSP AND issuetype = Story'
issues = jira.jql(jql_request)
print(issues)
```

But this doesn't list all the JIRAs (only the first 50). I want to iterate through the next batch. [Iterating through Jira API Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877366/iterating-through-jira-api-url) post describes the setting of parameter startAt if I use the REST method.

I want to know how I can specify using the Python SDK method. More specifically, it is not mentioned in the API documentation: https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/jira.html#get-issues-from-jql-search-result-with-all-related-fields

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer:

It needs to be set at `jira.jql(jql_request, start=<initial value>)` and then keep updating it based on the total results you get.

```
from atlassian import Jira

# Initialize Jira instance
jira = Jira(
    url='https://your-site.atlassian.net',
    username='email',
    password='token',
    cloud=True)

# Set the initial startAt value and maxResults value
start_at = 0
max_results = 50  # The maximum number of results per page, limited by Jira API

# Run a loop to retrieve all pages of search results
while True:
    # Make a JQL request with the start
    jql_request = 'project = WSP AND issuetype = Story'
    issues = jira.jql(jql_request, start=start_at)
    # print(issues)  # Process the retrieved issues as needed

    # Check if there are more issues beyond the current page
    if len(issues) < max_results:
        break  # Break the loop if no more issues are found

    # Increment the startAt value to retrieve the next page of results
    start_at += max_results
```